# Use same macro file for network

Tags: vba, excel

We are trying to create a single file that everyone on our network can pull from for their macros.

We want a way to have the code update without everyone updating it separately.

Is there a way to have everyone update their macros to a new style that will pull from this single location and allow us to be able to update the code at will?

The potential issue is, with so many people using the macros, if anyone leaves it open, it could stop us from updating the code because it is open elsewhere.

Comment: You can export the code modules and import them, this relies on access to the VBA project though, something that may not be possible.  Is a shared WB solution not a possibility?

Comment: Most of our macros are user forms, but there are a few that are workbooks, but they are all separate due to the information we are working with.

Comment: Do you have your own personal macros? Or rather you all use common macros that everyone in network has?

Comment: Common macros for the most part, there are a few that have personal macros due to their situation. But the majority are all the same.

Comment: We use an Excel add-in for this.  Set the .xlam read-only and do *not* "copy to folder" when adding to Excel.  This way everyone loads the same read-only copy of the addin from the network when they open Excel.  Updates involve either replacing the .xlam on the network or using a 'deploy' macro (set read/write>set isaddon=false>save new copy>set isaddon=true>set read-only).  Let me know if you'd like more detail.

Comment: We have them set up as add-ins in a central folder. But currently we have a makeshift installer that copies them over to the user's computer into their macro folder for use. I think we would definitely like more info @Snachmo.

Comment: Sounds like you're halfway there, only trick is to add the .xlam to Excel from a network location rather than copying it to the macro folder.  If Excel sees the .xlam is on a network it will prompt you to "Copy myaddin.xlam to the Addins folder for User?"  Select no, and it will re-load this .xlam from the network every time the user starts Excel (the add-in will not be available outside the network, which may be a deal breaker).  I think [this writeup](http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment) covers everything.

Comment: That is perfect! Unless our network is down, it'll work great. But when our network is down, we can't really do anything anyway! Thanks!!